# Is "to deoptimise" a correct verb?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, vocabulary

Can the verb "to deoptimise" be used in English? (=to make less optimal)

I could not find it in dictionaries such as Collins / Cambridge / Macmillan.

However, websites such as Wiktionary / Yourdictionary / Wordsense do define it.

Also - I could not find many instances of its usage.

If "to deoptimise" is incorrect, what is the antonym of "to optimise", ideally one using the "optim" root?

Comment: What is an example of a sentence where you would want to use it? The opposite of the most common usage of "to optimize" is to make something as inefficient as possible. Are you actually asking about undoing optimization that has already happened?

Comment: @ColleenV You can find some examples here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330172/what-verb-form-is-correct

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information so that people reading it don’t have to read the comments or follow a link to a different page to understand it.

Comment: More information on context would be useful. Make what less optimal, in what sense? user's answer below seems pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one can use "deoptimise"/"deoptimize". I have heard it used and have probably used it at least once myself. Language evolves based on the way its speakers use it. New words that weren't previously recognized as official words become words when people use them enough. The fact that it has a consistent definition across several dictionary sites is an indication that it has gained some widespread traction.

Here are some example usages in the wild:

- A slideshow by the V8 (the JavaScript engine for the Chromium browser) devs from Google: ["Deoptimization in V8"](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Z6oCocRASCfTqGq1GCo1jbULDGS-w-nzxkbVF7Up0u0/htmlpresent)
- An academic paper: ["Debugging optimized code with dynamic deoptimization"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/143103.143114)

Comment: In the context that you've shown examples of the meaning is "to remove prior optimization" not "to make less optimal".

Comment: @starball thank you. I found "deoptimise" in various similar scientific papers and coding articles, the problem is that they are seemingly written by non native speakers, hence I am not sure if they are using it properly.